# When designing a world with advanced parameters, how to increase the number of animal people?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

In the generated worlds of Dwarf Fortress (0.47.04), there are various types and species of [animal people](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Animal_person) ("intelligent wilderness creatures") who can create and join civilizations, like magpie men and snail people. This is one of my absolute favorite things about Dwarf Fortress, and I always love playing animal people adventurers and having animal people crop up in my worlds.

Similarly, you can [make a world with advanced parameters](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Advanced_world_generation). When selecting the menu option of "Design World with Advanced Parameters," you can tweak a lot of the parameters of the world generation algorithm to influence different things, such as the number of werebeasts and large monsters, the amount of water, and the prevalence of different minerals.

However, in this menu, I can't find any parameters to increase the number of animal people that generate in the world - which I would love to do, given how fun they are to have in a world. There are some options that are clearly related to
generating different civilization types, but nothing that seems related to animal people.

- One of the options is **"Number of Civilizations"** (0-300, default 40), which, according to the wiki, only works for the five base races of the game: dwarf, elf, human, goblin, and kobold. Thus, increasing this option doesn't affect the number of animal people.
- Another is **"Desired Good/Evil Square Counts."** According to the wiki, these values change the amount of good or evil tiles on the map, depending on the size of the region they are being considered for. I thought maybe this would alter animal people spawns, but there doesn't seem to be any basis for that happening, so this option doesn't work either.

So, either there is no current way to do this or I've missed something, hence my question. **How do I increase the number/spawn rate of animal people in world generation through advanced world parameters, or other means?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Humanoid (and giant) animal creatures are native to savage biomes, so increasing the savagery of your world might increase their numbers as well.
Keep in mind that typically only elves settle in savage regions, so cranking up the savagery of a world too much could shaft the other civilizations. At the extreme end they might even struggle getting enough initial site locations at world gen.

Comment: This is a really good suggestion. Will try this out :)